# Laravel foreign key

Tags: laravel, categories, foreign-key-relationship, eloquent

Here I meet a small problem with my code, no error but nothing appears (my categories didn't appears).

I have stored in a table of products a foreign key with an id category (I have a table with all my categories).

I have stored in a table of products a foreign key with an id category identifier (I have a table with all my categories). When I display my products, I try to retrieve the data of the category associated with the eloquent and relation system because I ignore how I have to do. It's seem to be work in database. However, no data is returned. What I'm trying to call the category data

Here are my data

App\Products :

```
class Products extends Model
{
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories');
    }
}
```

App\Categories :

```
    class Categories extends Model
{
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products');
    }
}
```

ProductsController :

```
public function index()
        {
            $renderProducts = Products::latest()->with('categories')->paginate(6);
            return view('produits.index', compact('renderProducts'));
        }
```

View :

```
 @foreach($renderProducts as $product)
            <div class="card-content">
              @if($product->categories)
                  <p>{{$product->categories->name}}</p>
              @endif
        </div>
@endforeach


Valeurs Tinker :

$product = App\Products::find(1)
=> App\Products {#729
     id: 1,
     title: "zzzz",
     description: "fzfzfezf",
     price: 33,
     created_at: "2017-05-26 15:57:30",
     updated_at: "2017-05-26 15:58:58",
     picture_url: "8484812.jpg",
     user_id: 1,
     categorie_id: 8,
   }
>>> $product->categories()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {#717}
>>> $product->categories()->associate($product)
=> App\Products {#729
     id: 1,
     title: "zzzz",
     description: "fzfzfezf",
     price: 33,
     created_at: "2017-05-26 15:57:30",
     updated_at: "2017-05-26 15:58:58",
     picture_url: "8484812.jpg",
     user_id: 1,
     categorie_id: 8,
     categories_id: 1,
     categories: App\Products {#729},
   }
```

No error occurred in my code. If anyone has a track to help me move forward, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about this:

`return view('produits.index', compact('renderProducts'));` `produits`?

Comment: I think the problem is your Model name